# Entity Framework / WebApi 2 permission check implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing a simple "Todo App" using ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6.1.0-alpha1. My aim is to restrict access, each user shall only view/edit their own Todos.

Example:

```
    // GET api/Todo/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Todo))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTodo(int id)
    {
        var todo = await _db.Todos.FindAsync(id);

        if (todo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (todo.CreatorId != _currentUser.Id)
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden); 
        }

        return Ok(todo);
    }
```

That is fine. Similar check added for delete, and on create it sets the CreatorId to the current user's id. However, I have a problem with updating.

I tried this:

```
    // PUT api/Todo/5
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTodo(int id, Todo todo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != todo.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }


        // --- No exception if I remove this block - BEGIN ---
        var original = await _db.Todos.FindAsync(id);

        if (original.CreatorId != _currentUser.Id || original.CreatorId != todo.CreatorId)
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        // --- No exception if I remove this block - END ---

        _db.Entry(todo).State = EntityState.Modified; // Exception thrown here

        try
        {
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TodoExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

However, a `System.InvalidOperationException` it thrown at the marked line:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**
>
> Attaching an entity of type 'ModernWeb.Domain.Models.Todo' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

If I remove the block with the FindByAsync(), it won't throw exception.

I also tried to use `_db.Entry(todo).OriginalValue`, but couldn't find a working syntax.

**How can I overcome this problem? Any best practice for situations like this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `FindAsync`, the entity instance returned is already attached to the context. So there is no reason for `_db.Entry(todo).State = EntityState.Modified;`

**Update**

I think I see what you are trying to do here. Try this instead:

```
var original = await _db.Todos.AsNoTracking()
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

if (original.CreatorId != _currentUser.Id || original.CreatorId != todo.CreatorId)
{
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
}
// --- No exception if I remove this block - END ---

_db.Entry(todo).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

When you invoke `.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync` instead of `FindAsync`, the `original` entity returned will not be attached to the context. Then you can set the one passed into the controller action as `Modified`, and since the context is not already tracking a different entity with the same id, you should not get that exception anymore.

As a secondary note, since the Todo entity passed into your argument already has an Id property, there shouldn't be a need to pass it in as a separate argument in the controller action. You should be able to do this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTodo(Todo todo)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || todo == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var original = await _db.Todos.AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == todo.Id);

    if (original == null) return NotFound();

    if (original.CreatorId != _currentUser.Id || original.CreatorId != todo.CreatorId)
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    _db.Entry(todo).State = EntityState.Modified; // Exception thrown here

    try
    {
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!TodoExists(todo.Id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: If omitting `_db.Entry(todo)`, I have to modify the properties of `original` manually, right? The big advantage of `_db.Entry(todo)` is that I don't have to manually update the properties. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this. Also, regarding your second note: the method (and its signature) was created by the Visual Studio scaffolding. Any ideas why did it create a separate `id` as well?

Comment: Say your entity had an id of TodoId instead of just Id. That's why the scaffolding generates the additional parameter.

Comment: No, it's Id is called `Id`.

Comment: ... and thats why you can omit the parameter from the controller action method.